# How to sync add-on for webpage highlighter, annotator?

Tags: firefox, sync, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, highlighting

I am using [Prostetnic highlighter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/prostetnic/) to highlight texts in webpages. It has a special benefit of reloading the highlights when I revisit the site. It stores the highlighted information in "patma.splite" file in the firefox profile directory.

But the problem I am facing is that though firefox syncs the add-ons between different computers, the "patma.splite" file doesn't get synced. That is why once highlighted page in one computer does not shown to be highlighted from other computer. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Or is there any other add-on which supports the syncing feature for mozilla or chrome?

P.S: I know many other highlighter like [Wired-Maker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wired-marker/), [Diigo](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/diigo-web-highlighter-and-stic/) etc. But What I am exactly looking for is an add-on which has mainly these two features:
(i) reload the highlights, annotations when I revisit the site.
(ii) it has the syncing feature between different computers. It doesn't matter if I need to use Dropbox or anything else to sync.

If there is no readymade add-on with the above two features, is there any easy way to get the features I am looking for ?
Thanks

Comment: Edit your question to remove the software recommendation part, or delete it altogether and post on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a solution to sync the "patma.splite" file using Dropbox. This file is situated in the ~/.mozilla/firefox/profile directory.If you don't know which one is your profile, just search the file in the ~/.mozilla/firefox/ directory.

First back up your file to a safe place.

The steps are:
(1) cut(not copy) the file ("patma.splite") to your Dropbox folder.
(2) make a soft link of the file there.
(3) now cut the link file to ~/.mozilla/firefox/profile directory.
(4) make sure to rename the link file name to patma.splite in case the link file name is different. If you use graphical user interface, the link file name would be "Link to patma.splite".

Now from other computer with which you want to sync, delete the patma.splite file from ~/.mozilla/firefox/profile directory. After that make a softlink of the "patma.splite" situated in your dropbox folder. This was the step 2 in the above. Now follow step 3 and 4. You are done.